# Parse json and get multiple values using Curl

Tags: json, curl

Trying to parse a json that was returned from CURL to get particular fields -

Name and Description.

These 2 fields will occur multiple times in the JSON and all the values should be printed

```
 [
  {
    "Attributes": {
      "Process Type": [
        "Process"
      ],
      "Process Dev. Status": [
        "Business Owner Signoff"
      ],
      "Total No. T-code/Components": [
        "7"
      ],
      "02. L3 Business Process": [
        "Customer InStore Execution"
      ],
      "Process Status": [
        "Pre-Approved"
      ],
      "RelatedSapEntities": [
        "0"
      ],
      "03. QA Occurences": [
        "2"
      ],
      "No of Replaced Tests": [
        "1"
      ],
      "01. Value ": [
        "Customer InStore"
      ]
    },
    "Description": "Process Description:\n\nThis Process will login to the application and creates the new Task.After the Task has been created it will go to the Calendario page and verify the given details. Then navigate to the Oggi page opens the ToDo link and change the status of the Task.Then it navigates to the Calendrio page and verify the changed status.Finally Logout from the application.\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n\nLayout :\n\nCISCISE_AdvisorCreateTask\n\nRecorset:\n\nCISCISE_AdvisorCreateTask\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n\nSub Process/Child Process/Utility: \n\n1. UTL_SF_Login\n2. SF_Web_Advisor_CreateNewTask\n3. SF_Web_Advisor_CalendarioPage\n4. SF_Web_CreatedTask_OggiPage\n5. SF_Web_Task_InCorso_To_Completato\n6. SF_Web_Task_CompletatoTask_OggiPage\n7. UTL_SF_Logout",
    "Database": "Certify",
    "ID": 12519,
    "Name": "CISCISE_Advisor_CreateTask",
    "Path": " Test Automation\\Training\\POC\\SF Italy\\SFWeb\\CISCISE_Advisor_CreateTask",
    "Project": " Test Automation"
  },
  {
    "Attributes": {
      "Process Type": [
        "Process"
      ],
      "Process Dev. Status": [
        "Business Owner Signoff"
      ],
      "Total No. T-code/Components": [
        "7"
      ],
      "No of Replaced Tests": [
        "1"
      ],
      "02. L3 Business Process": [
        "Customer InStore Execution"
      ],
      "Process Status": [
        "Pre-Approved"
      ],
      "RelatedSapEntities": [
        "0"
      ],
      "03. QA Occurences": [
        "2"
      ],
      "01. Value Stream": [
        "Customer InStore"
      ]
    },
    "Description": "Process Description:\n\nThis Process creates a new Out of Office event.\nCalendario page is verified that whether the event created is populated in it. Calendar Details are verified.\nA new OOO event is created again for the same date and time and the error message obtained is validated.\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n\nLayout :\n\nCISCISE_SalesRep_OutOfOffice\n\nRecorset:\n\nCISCISE_SalesRep_OutOfOffice\n\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n\nSub Process/Child Process/Utility: \n\n1. UTL_SF_Login\n2. SF_Web_Create_OutOfOffice\n3. SF_Web_CreatedOutOfOffice_CalendrioPage\n4. SF_Web_Create_OutOfOffice\n5. SF_Web_OutOfOffice_Error\n6. UTL_SF_Logout",
    "Database": "Certify",
    "ID": 11610,
    "Name": "CISCISE_SalesRep_OutOfOffice",
    "Path": " Test Automation\\Training\\POC\\SF Italy\\SFWeb\\CISCISE_SalesRep_OutOfOffice",
    "Project": " Test Automation"
  }
]
```

How to loop into this code and should I parse or stringfy the code given above?

Please tell me what to do to get the output?

Comment: whar have you tired?

Comment: I tried to use AWF Print. But unable to get all the Name and description